# J4 - Return to Component Dashboard from Options

Tags: joomla-4, component-configuration, dashboard

I've implemented a dashboard into a component with an option to update the components configuration parameters.  What I want to do is return to the dashboard on Save of the options.
I notice that there is a "path" and "return" element to the URL in the link element of the menu option I've created but I can't seem to get the return back to the dashboard.

```
    <menuitem
        title="COM_MYCOMPONENT_CONFIGURATION"
        type="component"
        element="com_config"
        link="index.php?option=com_config&amp;view=component&amp;component=com_mycomponent&amp;path=&amp;return="
    />
```

Does anyone know how to do this?  All pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the return part in the url to achieve want you want.
Basically, the return= is the base64encoded string of the last used url or whatever url you want.

```
//To compute the return
$return = base64_encode(\JRoute::_('index.php?option=mycomponent&view=dashboard'));

//To show what is the base64 encoded dashboard url
echo $return;
```

```
<menuitem
        title="COM_MYCOMPONENT_CONFIGURATION"
        type="component"
        element="com_config"
        link="index.php?option=com_config&amp;view=component&amp;component=com_mycomponent&amp;path=&amp;return=PASTE_THE_CONTENT_OF_THE_BASE64_ENCODED_DASHBOARD_URL_HERE"
    />
```

If you cannot do it via php use an online tool to compute the base64 encoded version of your dashboard url then paste it after return=

Comment: Ahh brilliant, thank you very much, I'll give that a go.  I didn't think of encoding the url.  Cheers.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy your day @GlennArkell